# Add application to page: not visible

Tags: facebook, tabs

I just added 3 applications to my page using:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=[appid]&next=[siteurl]

That all works fine, it redirects me to the [siteurl].

However, the apps don't show up on the page. In "Edit Page" -> "Apps" the apps also aren't visible.

Any idea what causes this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

The problem was that I defined the secure page url, but not the non-secure page url (while we don't use the non-secure page url anymore?)...

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the app is in sandbox mode and the account you're checking the "edit page -> apps" section does not have a role within your app, so they can't see it.

The dialog could also be failing. It's fairly recent and I've spotted bugs with it already. Try using http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=APP_ID&pages=1, replacing APP_ID with your app's ID, to see if that's working.